# Как у элемента background-color сделать на всю ширину экрана

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У логотипа `background-color` задается по ширине контейнера.

Как его можно задать на всю ширину экрана?

Всё лишнее я убрал, оставил самое необходимое:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1310px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 100px;
}

.header__top-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 80px;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .header__top-container {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: baseline;
    height: auto;
  }
  .header__logo {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 23px;
    padding-bottom: 23px;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container header__top-container">
  <div class="header__logo">
    <a class="header__logo-img" href="" aria-label="Главная страница">
      <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.svg?v=a010291124bf" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="header__top-main">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Нужно задавать фон тому элементу, который занимает всю ширину экрана (а не логотипу). В Вашем случае это header__top-container.

Comment: @humster_spb тогда у меня и нижняя часть закрасится, а мне нужно закрасить только верхнюю часть. Можно ли это как то сделать?

Comment: @kaucap, фон по определению применяется только к области элемента и не может выходить за его пределы. Вариант 1 (самый правильный): обернуть нужный элемент в еще один, который будет занимать всю ширину экрана. Вариант 2: использовать `box-shadow` - тень элемента может располагаться вне его. Вариант 3: задать элементу толстенные `border-left` и `border-right` (правда, придется повозиться с позиционированием и убиранием скроллинга). Вариант 4: использовать псевдоэлементы `:before / :after`, сделав из них пустые блоки с боков.

Comment: @Инквизитор Благодарю от души! Воспользовался вашим советом, помогло